# should I store a reference to the parent viewmodel in the child viewmodel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So if I store the parent ViewModel's reference in the child ViewModel will that be a crime ? Will I break MVVM rules ? My child view is a Window with a context menu. When the appropriate menu item is selected a new child view needs to be created. The parent only is responsible to create the child view. So keeping a reference to the parent view model, will do lot of good for me. At the same time I do not want to break the pattern rules.

```
class MainViewModel
{
    List<ChildViewModel> _childrenViewModels = new List<ChildViewModel>();

    public AddChild(ChildViewModel childViewModel)
    {
        _childrenViewModels.Add(childViewModel);
        childViewModel.Owner = this;
    }
}

class ChildViewModel
{
    private Child _child;
    public MainViewModel Owner { get; set; }

    public ChildViewModel(Child child)
    {
        _child = child;
    }
}
```

Comment: The patterns are just a guideline to get you started; no more. Only if you find yourself straying far from the pattern, theshould you look about and see if you have chosen the wrong pattern.

Comment: Patterns aren't meant to create architecture, they are meant to address issues that may arise within the architecture. The simplest way to ensure business objective and integrity is the right way.

Comment: `So if I store the parent ViewModel's reference in the child ViewModel will that be a crime` - Absolutely NO. Who told you that? It's perfectly OK that ANY ViewModel have a reference to ANY other ViewModel (as long as it doesn't hold references to UI Elements). The idea of MVVM is to separate presentation from behavior, not create a lot of restrictions that prevent you from writing clean code.

Comment: Nicely said HighCore.

Comment: Watch out for circular dependencies - obviously if you are doing constructor injection and unit testing you might find that A depends on B and B depends on A, which can be a code smell. I'm not saying don't keep a ref to the parent, but there should be a reason for it - what's the reason here? Can you not use a bubbling event/action or the event aggregator pattern?

Answer (score 3):

NO. In general if you use this technique many times try to hide it behind an abstraction, in fact this is what the famous [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com) [I love it] project does with its [IChild interface](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro.Core/IChild.cs

Answer (score 3):

While this pattern is not at all a crime or "code smell", it may in many situations work better to pass a reference to the parent in the form of an implementer of an interface, rather than as its own class. Thus, only the properties or methods the child needs to access in the parent are defined in the interface, but the child isn't given access to other public methods or properties of the parent class, which could cause bugs if used by mistake. This may involve a bit more code, but the looser connection between classes may offer benefits. If nothing more, it helps make the connection between child and parent more self-documenting and easier for people reading the code to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, but for your purpose, why do you need this reference if all the parent is doing is creating the child viewmodel. What is the purpose of having that linkage?

Comment: I need the reference because when the user selects a particular menu item from the context menu of the child view, it should create a new window. Now I want to leave it up to the parent (main) view to creation of child views and windows. But the event is happening in the child view. Maybe we could also do event routing ? I don't know, WPF is so big, no matter how many books I read I can't remember it all. Hence I am working on this project to really figure it out.